# No data on Application Insights

Tags: azure, monitoring, azure-application-insights

I have Application Insights SKD on a ASP.NET application, but i can't see data on Azure Portal, I have followed the official documentation for troubleshoot and the connectivity with dc.services.visualstudio.com seems to be fine but i can't connect to f5.services.visualstudio.com, but f5.services.visualstudio.com seems not used anymore, I can't access it inside and outside of my network. 
The account have access to Performance Logs too, and I uninstalled the SCOM Monitoring Agent to prevent problems, but still no data!

Comment: what version of the sdk are you using?   how are you setting your instrumentation key?  are you seeing outbound requests to dc.services.visualstudio.com that include telemetry?

Comment: It's the latest version of SDK, I've already reconfigured the instrumentation key, I tryied to connect to by telnet dc.services.visualstudio.com, I can use Fiddler to found the outbund request.

Comment: and the outbound data has the expected ikey in it?  and it was accepted and a 200 response?

Comment: and "latest" version of which sdk? i'm just trying to make sure i have exactly the right answers for you.  is it the javascript sdk?  is it the asp.net specific sdk?  is it the new asp.net 5 specific sdk?  we have lots of sdks :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that assemblies are included in your project
2. Check you have last SDK version of Application Insights installed
3. Check ApplicationInsights.config file exists in the root of application and instrumentation key is presented
4. If you resolve InstrumentationKey from web.config or from another place, debug your application and ensure the InstrumentationKey is really resolved
5. Check your telemetries are collecting using the Visual Studio Diagnostics Hub (developer mode must be set to TRUE - by default)
6. Try to send more telemetries or change the flush interval to 0
7. First place where you can check your telemetries is Azure Portal - Diagnostic Search blade
8. Try to check quotas on Azure Portal